# Python import order wrong after installing something else

Tags: python, import, path

Basically I am getting libs from 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' (well '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg')
before 
'/u/arvie/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'

I have tried playing with the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONUSERBASE and have not gotten anywhere.  This issue happened after I installed a package from git (which I deleted after it caused this mess).

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import theano
theano.__fileUsing gpu device 0: GeForce GTX TITAN X
>>> theano.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg/theano/__init__.pyc'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easydict-1.6-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysrt-1.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/u/arvie/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
>>> import site
>>> site.getuserbase()
'/u/arvie/.local/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your python sys path is quite complicated and you may want to clean that up a bit for long term stability. But for a quick fix of your problem try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(desired_location, module_name)
```

The location number should be ahead of the directory you don't want the module to be loaded from.

Comment: Thanks.  Well that works but I'm not happy about it :(  I'm not sure why my path is getting so complicated.

I'd give you and upvote but I cant with my rep.